# Code meaning in JavaScript "document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have this code and I tried to explain each line however, I got told line 6 and 7 of my explanation was incorrect and I don't really understand what the code mean or does.
Any help?
Thank you

```
1)  <!DOCTYPE html>  
2)  <html>
3)  <body>
4)  <h1>Task 1 code</h1>
5)  <p id="msg">Now you see me.</p>
6)  <button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Gone!'">
Click Me!</button>
7)  <button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Back again!'">
Bring me back!</button>
8)  </body>
9)  </html>
```

And here is my explanation:

- The first line will make a comment on the script.
- The second line will create and open a HTML script.
- The third line will open the body tag.
- The fourth line will create a level one header, it will display ‘Task 1 code’ as the title, and it will close it.
- The fifth line will make a new paragraph, it will have an identification called ‘msg’, and in the identification, it will have the sentence ‘now you see me’ and then close the paragraph.
- The sixth line will create a stranded button form, which responds with one click. When it is clicked, it will get the element of the id and change the header to ‘Gone!’ if the ‘Click me!’ button is clicked.
- The seventh line will create a standard button form that will respond with one click, it will get the element from the id, and it will change the header to ‘Back again when the “Bring me back!” button is clicked
- The eighth line will close the body tag.
- The ninth line will close the HTML script.

Comment: *the first line will create a html script* , one can discuss if html is really a scripting language...

Comment: *will respond with one click* ??

Comment: there are some sites on the net that give explanations and examples to the basic elements of html and javascript, for example the mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What lines 6 and 7 do are as follows:

When you click the button "Click Me!", it gets the element with an id of 'msg', and changes the `innerHTML`—what is visually displayed on the page.

```js
cur = 1

function start(){
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = cur;
  cur+=1;
  setTimeout(start, 1000);
}
start();
```

```html
<p id="msg">1</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the misuse of the word "header". Clicking the button on line six will change the text of the `<p>` with id message to "Gone!". The button on seven will change it to "Back Again!".

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your use of the word 'header' is what's causing the problem. The innerHTML method changes the p tag 'content'. Hope this helps.